# Array type column in Database

Tags: php, database, postgresql, types

I am storing some data in a table. I have to use the datatype real[]. How do i access the elements or is there a special method to get the array from the table?

i am trying to access the single elements like this:

```
$forceData = "SELECT daten_force FROM pfc where pfcid=1";
$forceResult = pg_query($forceData);
$forceData = pg_fetch_row($forceResult);

for($i = 0; $i < count($travelData); $i++){
    echo /*$travelData[$i].*/",".$forceData[$i];
}
```

Comment: i dont understand ur question nor your problem.

Comment: In SQL you can use `SELECT daten_force[1]` to select the first element.

Comment: Laurenz Albe you are right!